# how to get each row of a csv file

Tags: javascript, csv

I am trying to read csv files using the 
code below

```js
var fileInput = document.getElementById("csv"),

    readFile = function () {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = reader.result;
        };
        // start reading the file. When it is done, calls the onload event defined above.
        reader.readAsBinaryString(fileInput.files[0]);
    };

fileInput.addEventListener('change', readFile);
```

```html
<p>Select local CSV File:</p>
<input id="csv" type="file">
    
<output id="out">
    file contents will appear here
</output>
```

it works fine but I need to print each row one by one not just the whole csv file at once. how do I do that

Comment: "*How do I do that*" - You either implement your own CSV parser, or just use any library you like from the internet to parse the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the text into lines using regex and then iterate over those lines to output as you desire.  The following still requires the whole file to be downloaded first (before it is parsed), but once loaded, you can parse it into lines and output it as desired (in this case line-by-line).  A timeout is used to exaggerate this example.

```js
// Create a delay using a promise
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

var fileInput = document.getElementById("csv"),

  readFile = function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function() {
      let lines = reader.result.split(/[\r\n]+/g)
      let output = document.querySelector('#out')

      const loop = async (lines,output) => {
        for(let line of lines) {
          await delay(333)
          output.innerHTML += line + '<br>'
        }
      }
      loop(lines,output)
    };
    // start reading the file. When it is done, calls the onload event defined above.
    reader.readAsBinaryString(fileInput.files[0]);
  };

fileInput.addEventListener('change', readFile);
```

```html
<p>Select local CSV File:</p>
<input id="csv" type="file">

<output id="out">
    file contents will appear here
</output>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can read and write it into array before printing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {readdata(data);}
 });
});

function readdata(textCsv) {
var record_num = 5;  // how many elements there are in each row
var allCsvLines = textCsv.split(/\r\n|\n/);
var entries = allCsvLines[0].split(',');
var lines = [];
var headings = entries.splice(0,record_num);
while (entries.length>0) {
    var tarr = [];
    for (var j=0; j<record_num; j++) {
        tarr.push(headings[j]+":"+entries.shift());
    }
    lines.push(tarr);
}
alert(lines);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method of file reader **readAsText** .It will work file

```js
var fileInput = document.getElementById("csv"),

    readFile = function () {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = reader.result;
        };
        // start reading the file. When it is done, calls the onload event defined above.
        reader.readAsText(fileInput.files[0]);
    };

fileInput.addEventListener('change', readFile);
```

```html
<p>Select local CSV File:</p>
<input id="csv" type="file">
    
<output id="out">
    file contents will appear here
</output>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to do it with stream to handle very large files, then

```js
// Simulate a file from input[type=file]
var csv = new Blob([
`apple,1,$1.00
banana,4,$0.20
orange,3,$0.79`])

// Use a fetch-Response hack to transform a file/blob into a stream
var stream = new Response(csv).body

var lines = 0
var stdout = new WritableStream({
  write (line, controller) {
    out.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', line)
    out.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<br>')
    
    lines++

    // Don't want to output to many lines, so we
    // abort the reading for the rest of the file
    if (lines >= 2) controller.close() 
  }
})

stream
  .pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream()) // polyfill
  .pipeThrough(new ByLineStream())
  .pipeTo(stdout)
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/GoogleChromeLabs/text-encode-transform-polyfill/master/text-encode-transform.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jimmywarting/web-byline/master/index.js"></script> 


<output id="out">
  file contents will appear here<br>
</output>
```